# Tailwind CSS custom color applying to text but not background in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

Okay so my problem is more than just as titled.
I have been trying to add customize the color in my React app, and have run into multiple problems.

Here's some of my code:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: "var(--color-primary)",
      secondary: "var(--color-secondary)",
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

```
// tailwind.css
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;

.theme-TCD {
  --color-primary: #411218;
  --color-secondary: #e8982e;
}
```

1. I originally setup my React app following [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/tailwindcss-react-project/) using npm but that would not work. When I follow [this tutorial](https://dev.to/hagnerd/setting-up-tailwind-with-create-react-app-4jd) using yarn, some custom colors are applying correctly.
2. Only custom text colors are applying, not bg colors.
3. Custom text color only applies if it's a React element. It doesn't work in a plain HTML tag.
   I.E.

```
import React from "react";
import Hello from "./hello";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="theme-TCD">
      <h1 className="text-primary">Hello World!</h1> // This does not work
      <Hello /> // This works
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inverting the order of appearance in your **tailwind.css** file and changing to :

```
:root {
  --color-primary: #411218;
  --color-secondary: #e8982e;
}

@tailwind  base;
@tailwind  components;
@tailwind  utilities;
```